# Transit visa for South Korea as a Pakistani citizen?

Tags: visas, south-korea, pakistani-citizens

I am taking a round trip from China to Japan. My departure flight has a 7-hour layover in Seoul, that would be okay, but on the return flight there is a layover of 24 hours. Can I get a transit visa for a 24 hour-stay at the airport? If not and I need to stay at the airport, how can I get a hotel at the airport online? Or I would just need to sit in the transit area for 24 hours?

P.S I have a Pakistani passport.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Korean transit visa required for Indians?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110091/korean-transit-visa-required-for-indians)

Comment: @Newton Indian is not Pakistani.

Comment: @MarkMayoI thought the answer had enough information for it to be general and not specific to Indians.

Comment: @Newton Understandable, but generally the idea is to close duplicate questions, not duplicate answers.

Comment: @MarkMayo so one can copy paste the answer here to address this question?

Comment: It's up to you to decide if you think you have a valid answer, and the community will upvote :)  Alternatively we can make a generic question that covers it, like the 'do I need a transit visa in UK' question

Answer (score 1):

As a Pakistani citizen, you will need a visa if you want to enter Korea. If you don't want to apply for a visa, or can't, there is a [Transit Hotel](https://www.walkerhill.com/transithotel/) in both terminals.

Most of the information is available on [HiKorea](https://www.hikorea.go.kr/pt/InfoDetailR_en.pt?categoryId=2&parentId=385&catSeq=401&showMenuId=375), although it's in bits and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Timatic](https://www.emirates.com/english/before-you-fly/visa-passport-information/find-visa-requirements-results.aspx?NC=PK&NV=Pakistan&AC=CN&AV=China&DC=JP&DV=Japan&TC=KR&TV=Korea%2C%20Republic%20of&h=4bc91324a8f1874cda517b52577c360caf4d816), the database used by airlines to check for document requirements (and courtesy of Emirates), you may transit without visa, but could not leave the

> Passport holder of Pakistan
>   Destination Japan
>   Transit countries/territories   Korea, Republic of
>
> **TWOV (Transit Without Visa):**
>
> Passengers transiting through Seoul (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Passengers transiting through Seoul (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country within 72 hours. They must:
>   - join a transit tour organized by Seoul (ICN), and
>   - have documents required for the next destination.
>
> Passengers with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third country on the same calendar day. They must stay in the international transit area of the airport and have documents required for the next destination.

The [Incheon Airport Transit Hotel](https://www.walkerhill.com/transithotel/) is located within Incheon International Airport’s departure lounge.