# korean transit Visa for Indian passport Holders

Tags: transit, indian-citizens, south-korea

I am a Indian National and living in UK. I came Japan last month to see my Husband. Now i am going back to India. My flight is from Tokyo-korea-New Delhi. I have a layover in korea about 12 hours. Do i need a transit Visa??? Please help me

Comment: Are both legs of the journey booked under one PNR or will you have to reclaim baggage in Korea before checking in for your onward flight?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Korean transit visa required for Indians?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/110091/korean-transit-visa-required-for-indians)

Comment: I disagree with the duplicate marking, as its only answer doesn't actually cover transiting in the airport, but only entering Korea during a layover.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a transit visa for Korea if you remain in the international transit area.

You don't need a transit visa to participate in the [Transit Tour](https://www.airport.kr/ap_cnt/en/trn/tour/trtour/trtour.do) program, so you may be able to leave the airport on a guided tour. Visit the green Transit Tour desk when you arrive at ICN for more details or to book a tour.

Timatic, the database which airlines use to verify passenger travel documents, states in relevant parts:

> TWOV (Transit Without Visa):
>   Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Seoul
>   (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country within 24 hours. They must stay in the international
>   transit area of the airport and have documents required for
>   the next destination.
>
> Visa required, except for Passengers transiting through Seoul
>   (ICN) with a confirmed onward ticket for a flight to a third
>   country within 72 hours. They must:
>
> - join a transit tour organized by Seoul (ICN), and
> - have documents required for the next destination.